# warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper' less than -source '1.8'

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I get this error message when I compile with Android Studio 3.1 and Kotlin. What I need to configure to avoid this warning?

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper' less than -source '1.8'
```

Answer (score 4):

That warning is a bug, that happens when you use kapt instead of annotationProcessor on some libraries, for example Room on version: 1.0.0 (fixed by using version: 1.1.0-beta2).

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I add `1.1.0-beta2` 

`[kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/serialization/jvm/JvmProtoBufUtil
 at me.eugeniomarletti.kotlin.metadata.KotlinClassMetadata$data$2.invoke(KotlinMetadata.kt:51) `

Comment: do you use same version on room::runtime library?

Answer (score 0):

Continue from @saba-21 answer.

The workaround:

1. change `kapt -> annotationProcessor` if you want to retain the room version
2. or just upgrade your room version to the latest stable currently [1.1.1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#1.1.1)